# No video output until system boots

Tags: graphics-card, uefi

When i start my PC I don't get any video output from my dedicated gpu (integrated works).

Specs:

- VGA: Radeon RX580 sapphire nitro+
- CPU: i5 3470
- MBD: from Dell Optiplex 7010
- Boot mode: UEFI
- UEFI Secure boot:Enabled, changing has no effect
- OS: windows 10, ubuntu 22.04 lts (I don't see grub boot menu with RX580 and uefi)

I tried:

-Changing "primary display" in bios (no effect)

-Connecting monitor to different port on graphics card (no effect)

-Connecting different gpu -> I got video from it but not from RX580

-Switching boot mode to "legacy" -> It works, but i have working OS installad on uefi, so I don't want to change it

-Enabling/disabling secure boot (no effect)

The gpu should support UEFI (documentation says it, and gpu-z shows it's vbios supports uefi)

Edit: I forgot to say that monitor shows "no signal" message, and the fans are running at high speed, until OS boots

Comment: "_integrated works_" - is that on the mainboard? does that output show the early-boot stuff you're missing from the RX580? ... can you disable the integrated graphics in the BIOS, or change the "_primary_" in the BIOS?

Comment: @Attie integrated graphics - in cpu (intel hd 2500), when i connect to it i can see post logo and bios settings, I already tried changing primary display to all avaliable graphics (rx 580, intel hd and auto -> no effect

Comment: Which output is missing? If you mean POST/boot then the BIOS usually only supports the integrated CPU.

Comment: @harrymc I'm not sure what do you mean, but I understand it like dedicated gpu shouldn't work during post. The problem is only with this specific gpu (rx 580) when i connect my old gpu (nvidia gt 730) it shows output normally

Comment: Just a guess that your BIOS doesn't know how to pilot the RX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few days ago my CMOS battery died and when I put there new one the GPU was working in bios (even if i set everything back to my custom settings). I don't know why it acts like that but when I put there back the old one there is no signal from the gpu again so I guess it was because it had low voltage? (no idea how it can affect this, but seems like that)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, it sounds like the GPU firmware is missing a resolution entry in its UEFI table, causing display not to initalize until it's handed off to the OS. Contact the GPU vendor to see if a firmware update is available for your specific GPU.

Comment: I tried searching on sapphire's support, but there is literally nothing usefull. I looked to techpowerup but found there only vBIOS 015.050.002.001.000000 with some mods, but that version I have currently. Is there any other vBIOS source?

Comment: Although you may have luck elsewhere on the internet, like TechPowerUp, the trusted source for VBIOS would be the vendor (i.e. Sapphire) - if they (or AMD) don't have a published tool you may have be able to email them.