# No signal from GPU on display(s) until OS boots

Tags: boot, multiple-monitors, hdmi, gpu, displayport

I switched recently to AMD RX 6600 and it has quite a strange issue.
If I plug in both of my displays (HDMI and DP), there is no signal for either of them until OS (Linux or Windows) finishes booting, then both work perfectly fine.
Same if I just plug in DP display.
Only if I have HDMI display plugged in it works right after the POST, so I can access UEFI setup and see bootloader screen.
I'd prefer both displays working from the moment I start my PC, is there anything I can do to diagnose / fix this?

My hardware:

Mobo: Asus PRIME X470-PRO

CPU: AMD Ryzen 5600

GPU: AMD Radeon RX 6600 manufactured by Biostar

Comment: Are both ports on the Graphics card ?

Comment: @RohitGupta yes, both displays are connected directly to the GPU.

Comment: Does the display driver allow turning off HDCP ? If it does, try disabling it.

Comment: @harrymc but isn't HDCP disableable on OS level? And the problem is that displays don't work before OS boots.

Comment: Perhaps the issue lies with the specific brand/model of AMD RX 6600 device you have. Did you do any research on that particular product? Spitballing here, it may even be the DP monitor that causes the issue

Comment: @JaromandaX I didn't find anything in particular regarding my graphics card that would be connected to my issue. I have also tried to connect DP monitor via HDMI (with only HDMI connected to GPU at the time) and it works just like the other monitor worked while plugged to HDMI. So I don't suppose this could be a monitor issue.

Comment: can you share the details of your graphics card? `I have also tried to connect DP monitor via HDMI` then it's not longer DP so, not sure what that proves

Comment: @JaromandaX right, when I plugged monitor that was previously connected through DP into HDMI slot, then it's no longer DP. My point was this is probably not monitor issue after all, as previously not working display connected through HDMI works. I also added some info about my rig, GPU included.

Answer (score 0):

The core issue sounds like a missing resolution on the GPU's EFI firmware table, i.e. a dupe of [No video output until system boots](https://superuser.com/questions/1802249/no-video-output-until-system-boots/)

This would require a firmware update to resolve.